# How to find out why is my cursor constantly flashing as busy/loading?

Tags: windows-7

My windows cursor started flashing between normal and busy/loading display. It's extremely annoying and distracting. I restarted the computer but it still happens since startup.

**Is there a way to tell which program tells windows to change the cursor** so that I can either uninstall, terminate or fix it? I tried to terminate processes randomly, but that's useless.

Comment: Which computer model? Does this happen when booting in Safe mode? In Task Manager have you tried to terminate all processes that have windows (Applications tab)?

Comment: I terminated all processes that do not run from windows system directory. I also checked startup programs and services that are running. I am using lenovo and I wouldn't be surprised if some of the lenovo garbageware was responsible for this issue. I just noticed interesting fact: it also causes Qt application to blur if it's running in debug mode from QtCreator.

Comment: Does it happen if you boot in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc Cannot tell, I fixed it already as you can see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this was a tough one! After purging ALL processes, restarting PC, checking out services and running CCleaner, I had a look in windows event log, which can be found at Start - Administrative Tools - Event Viewer.

And I found this errors, a lot of them:

```
Faulting application name: mDNSResponder.exe, version: 3.0.0.10, time stamp: 0x4e5dc964
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0xffffffff
Faulting process id: 0xeb0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2bdfb6d7b83dc
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Blizzard\Bonjour Service\mDNSResponder.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: ab2c3d43-29ee-11e7-8e4f-6c8814f41a34
```

I remember this executable, popping out in task manager. But it pops for just a short moment. It was obviously installed along with the official free release of StarCraft by Blizzard.

I solved the problem immediately by renaming the executable to `mDNSResponder.exe.bak`. After this, more errors - which I expected since I removed the executable - appeared in System tab:

```
The Bonjour Service service failed to start due to the following error: 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I went to `services.msc` and set Bojour Service to `Manual` from `Automatic`.

Comment: For a complete procedure see [What Is mDNSResponder.exe / Bonjour and How Can I Uninstall or Remove It?](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6456/what-is-mdnsresponder.exe-bonjour-and-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-it/)